# .htaccess rewrite to redirect domain.com to domain.net/subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect `somedomain.tv` to `anotherdomain.com/tv` and (if possible) keep the URL as `somedomain.tv`

My .htaccess so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^radiouas\.tv$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.radiouas\.tv$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.radiouas\.org\/tv" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# This simply redirects but does not keep the original URL
```

I have found many ways to do that when you have only one domain (e.g. domain.com to domain.com/blog). But in my case, I'm using two different domains...

How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the domains running on the same server?

Comment: Yes they are...

Comment: Are they on the same web root?

Comment: Radiouas.tv is not linked to any account (yet?)

Comment: If Radiouas.tv is on the same web root as the .org, you should be able to do something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /tv/$1 [L]` (leaving the `RewriteCond`s in place)

Comment: Well, the common sense tells me that the .htaccess should be in the root of radiouas.tv but I don't have any account associated to that domain. So radiouas.org is the original domain with a cPanel account. Does this affect the desired behaviour?

Comment: for internal RewriteRules setup in .htaccess to work, both domains need to share the same web root. Whether that is possible to do in your server setup I don’t know